# How to select data from list of pairs given that one entry of each element is element of another list

Tags: list-manipulation, data

I have data of the following form

```
data={{6, 23.3}, {6.1, 19.8}, {6.2, 25.1}, {6.3, 25.5}, {6.4, 24.5}, {6.5, 
  28.1}, {6.6, 24.9}, {6.7, 26.3}, {6.8, 27.3}, {6.9, 27.7}, {7, 
  33.9}, {7.1, 26.6}, {7.2, 31.3}, {7.3, 26.8}, {7.4, 31.5}, {7.5, 
  30.2}, {7.6, 29.8}, {7.7, 25.5}, {7.8, 31.5}, {7.9, 28.9}, {8, 
  28.1},...,}
```

This is a very long list of pairs, which are of the form $(t,B)$, time and magnetic field magnitude. Then I used a code to find relevant points that I need to use. Namely the peaks of the magnetic field. With the help of `FindPeak` I found that the Peak Magnetic moments are

```
peaks={{15, 31.5}, {99, 31.6}, {170, 45.7}, {224, 15.7}, {281, 15.6}, {319, 
  13.1}, {345, 10.5}, {349, 11.1}, {437, 8.4}}
```

I also found the corresponding time using `peaktime = data[[First /@ peaks, 1]]`

What I wish is to create a list of pairs, of the form $(t_p,B_p)$ such that $t_p$ and $B_p$ are the peak times and magnetic field magnitudes, respectively. For this I used a For loop, which is the following:

```
v = {};
For[i = 1, i <= Length[peaktime], i++, 
 u = Position[data[[All, 1]], peaktime[[i]]][[1]]; 
 v = Union[v, u]]
peakscouuple = data[[v, All]];
```

This works, but it is too messy, Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: A minimum _working_ example would be useful ...

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you can just use `data[[First/@peaks]]` without the spec to take the first part like you used in `peaktime=data[[...,1]]` to get (t,B) pair corresponding to the peaks.

Comment: You could also use `Extract[data,Position[PeakDetect[Last/@data],1]]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
data = {{6, 23.3}, {6.1, 19.8}, {6.2, 25.1}, {6.3, 25.5}, {6.4, 24.5}, {6.5, 28.1},
  {6.6, 24.9}, {6.7, 26.3}, {6.8, 27.3}, {6.9, 27.7}, {7, 33.9}, {7.1, 26.6}, 
  {7.2, 31.3}, {7.3, 26.8}, {7.4, 31.5}, {7.5, 30.2}, {7.6, 29.8}, {7.7, 25.5}, 
  {7.8, 31.5}, {7.9, 28.9}, {8, 28.1}};

Pick[data, PeakDetect[data[[All, 2]]], 1]
```

> {{6, 23.3}, {6.5, 28.1}, {7, 33.9}, {7.2, 31.3}, {7.4, 31.5}, {7.8, 31.5}}

Answer (score 2):

```
data[[FindPeaks[data[[All, 2]]][[All, 1]]]]
```